# Can my son enter the United States with just his birth abroad certificate?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, children, mexican-citizens

I have been working to get my family into the United States for over a year. My wife is Mexican and son was born there. My wife got her permanent resident visa just 2 months ago, and my son had his birth abroad certificate approved just a week ago.

Would there be any problems crossing with just my son's birth abroad certificate as evidence, if we cross as a family? We would have other proof that the child is ours, like Mexican birth certificate, hospital certificate etc. My son is 3 months old.

Comment: By "birth abroad certificate" do you mean the *consular report of birth abroad* (CRBA)? Are you entering by land or air?

Comment: I am entering by land

Answer (score 5):

You will be fine.

> ## What types of documents are accepted for entry into the United States via land and sea?
>
> ...
>
> U.S. and Canadian citizen children under the age of 16 (or under 19, if traveling with a school, religious group, or other youth group) need only present a birth certificate or other proof of citizenship. The birth certificate can be original, photocopy, or certified copy.

A consular report of birth abroad is not a birth certificate, but it is definitely "other proof of citizenship."

Source: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative