# US citizen born in Mexico. Do I need a Mexico passport to travel to Mexico by plane?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, mexico

I was born in Mexico and I became a US citizen through naturalization. I am going to travel to Mexico for vacation. Do I need a Mexico passport to travel? Or can I just travel with my US passport?

Comment: See the above. To enter Mexico as a Mexican citizen, you'd want to show one of the listed documents, but it doesn't need to be a Mexican passport. You'll need your US passport, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You need a US passport to re-enter the US by air.

To enter Mexico, you should have a Mexican passport **or** one of the documents listed [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/do-dual-american-and-mexican-citizens-need-passports-to-travel-between-the-us-an)